# How to add row name to cell in pandas dataframe?

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas

How do I take data frame, like the following:

```
d = {'col1': [1, 2], 'col2': [3, 4]}
df = pd.DataFrame(data=d)
df

      col1    col2
row0   1   3
row1   2   4
```

And produce a dataframe where the row name is added to the cell in the frame, like the following:

```
        col1     col2
row0   1,row0   3,row0
row1   2,row1   4,row1
```

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Please clarify the use-case. This seems to be a backwards step in a flat file format.  Additionally, the dict definition you provide will **not** create the Dataframe you have shown.  The indices will be `0, 1`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can convert the dtype to string and add the index to the dataframe:

```
print(df,'\n')
print(df.astype(str).add(","+df.index,axis=0))
```

---

```
      col1  col2
row0     1     3
row1     2     4 

        col1    col2
row0  1,row0  3,row0
row1  2,row1  4,row1
```